# Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke, marshalling, dllimport

I am trying to use a function from a c dll, in a c# application, I am facing this error each time i try to run the application and call the function in question.
At first i thought maybe this is because of the wrong signature i am using, but i tried to make it as simple as possible yet no luck.!
To cut a long story short:
This is my actual source code for c dll :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
extern "C"
{
    struct teststruct
    {
        char acharacter;
        int  anumber;
        char* astring;
        char  anarray[10];
        const char* conststring;
    };

    __declspec(dllexport) teststruct  TestDLL()
    {
        teststruct stc;
        stc.acharacter = 'A';
        stc.anumber = 10;
        strcpy(stc.anarray, "Test");
        stc.astring = "astring!";
        stc.conststring = "Crash?";

        return stc;
    }
}
```

And this is the c# counter part:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct teststruct
{
    public char acharacter;
    public  int anumber;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string astring;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public char[] anarray;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string conststring;
}

namespace Tcp_connections_list
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        [DllImport("simple c dll.dll",CallingConvention= CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern teststruct TestDLL();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnTestDll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            teststruct test = TestDLL(); //Crash at the very begining!
            textBox1.Text = test.acharacter.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = test.anarray.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = test.anumber.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = test.astring.ToString();
            textBox1.Text = test.conststring.ToString(); 


        }

    }
}
```

The following code snippet gives me the same exact error, I changed the structure to

```
struct teststruct
{
    char acharacter;
    int  anumber;
};
```

and its C# equivalent to

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct teststruct
{
    public char acharacter;
    public  int anumber;
}
```

to make it as simple as possible, Yet again i get the same exact error!
What am i missing here?

Comment: FWIW your unmanaged code is C++ rather than C

Comment: Why is it C++? it uses only c headers and c statements plus its in a extern c block!!?

Comment: It is C++. I can tell that because you use `extern "C"` which is not valid C. What's more you refer to the struct as `teststruct` which would not be valid in C. In C it would be `struct teststruct`, or you'd have to add a `typedef`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the marshalling of the null-terminated C strings. You cannot expect the p/invoke marshaller to deal with those in a function return value. The struct needs to be declared like this:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public struct teststruct
{
    public byte acharacter; // don't use C# char which is 2 bytes wide
    public int anumber; 
    public IntPtr astring;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 10)]
    public char[] anarray;
    public IntPtr conststring;
}
```

You'll need to use `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi` to extract the contents of the C strings.

As a more general piece of advice, passing large structs as function return values is a bad idea. There is no single generally accepted ABI for doing that. Different compilers handle this in different ways. Better is to allocate the struct in the calling code, and pass its address. Like this:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void TestDLL(teststruct *ts)
{
    ts->... = ...;
    ...
}
```

And on the C# side:

```cs
[DllImport(...)]
public static extern void TestDLL(out teststruct ts);
```

In fact, it would not surprise me if the struct that you are trying to work with cannot be marshalled as a return value. You really should pass it as an `out` parameter.

Comment: Thank you very much :) 
ACtually i tried to use a pointer justlike you suggested.But i am only going to use the structure for output stuff in c#, using ref makes me initialize the structure in advance! again if i do teststruct ts = new teststruct();     and continue running the sample i get this error ;
http://pastebin.com/TQqKiEDL
If i use out instead i get the same exact error .
in the details of the happened exception i see:
"The name '$exception' does not exist in the current context"
What should i do ?

Comment: I realised that I mis-read your code. You aren't writing to uninitialized memory. I fixed the answer.

Comment: Thanks, then again why am i getting the stated error?! Simply doing :
 teststruct test;    
            test.acharacter = 0;
            test.anumber = 0;
            TestDLL(ref test);    just doesnt work and gives this error http://pastebin.com/TQqKiEDL !;

Comment: You've changed your code. Most likely the native and managed no longer match up. Perhaps you failed to re-compile the native code.

Comment: yes i changed it, but compiled and builded it as well, the none reference functgion works well , but when it comes to the ref version it generates the exception . here is the code : http://pastebin.com/6FLT019n  ,By the way, thats test2.acharacter and so on, not test.character

Comment: But you also removed the specification of the calling convention as being `Cdecl`. Put that back and its all good. You need to put it on all your p/invokes.

Comment: sorry to ask again, but why when i changed the structure i get an error ? :http://pastebin.com/v73yPEC9

Comment: So I guess you need to go back to use a `ref` or `out` param.

Comment: Do it as per the final part of my answer. In other words, do not use the struct as the return value.

Comment: I am not, actually i am following your advise on using the out parameter on the struct : http://pastebin.com/Wye06Ay1

Comment: No. Your C# code needs to declare functions that return void.

Comment: Oh My God :-) I got it, Thanks a quadrillion again :-D

Comment: ByValTStr might be better for that fixed length inline char array. That should allow you to declare the var as string which will be more convenient.