# Marshal callback in a struct from C++ to C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct, callback, marshalling

I need to return the necessary information about an object as a struct with callbacks and other data.

This is what it looks like on the C# side:

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public delegate void ChartAddDataCallback(IntPtr data, int size);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct ChartAccessors
{
    public IntPtr HWnd;
    public ChartAddDataCallback addDataCallback;
}

[DllImport("CppPart.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "GetAccessors")]
public static extern ChartAccessors GetAccessors();
```

The C++ "mirrored" version looks like this:

```
typedef void(__cdecl *AddDataCallback) (int * data, int size);

struct ChartAccessors
{
    HWND m_chartHWnd;
    AddDataCallback m_addDataCallback;
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) ChartAccessors GetAccessors();
```

Usage:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ChartAccessors accessors = GetAccessors();
}
```

However, when i start up the program i get the exception "Method's type signature is not PInvoke compatible."
It works if i use any other return type (like int or float) instead of the struct.

Comment: How do you call it, can you share the example? You can try modify `GetAccessors();` method to return `IntPtr` and than use `Marshal.PtrToStructure` method

Comment: And check this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-data-with-platform-invoke maybe you've missed something in C++ declaration

Comment: Hi Pavel, thanks for you response. I added the usage (which is rather simplistic).
I tried to return it as an IntPtr and marshal it to the structure but that is giving me a fatal error.
i returned it from C++ like this ->  return new ChartAccessors();

Comment: Try to check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803083/methods-type-signature-is-not-pinvoke-compatible It can be a problem with charset and C/C++ strings

Comment: there are no strings involved in my program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Marshal.PtrToStructure was actually solving this issue, as [Pavel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4728685/pavel-anikhouski) pointed out.

```
void RegisterCallbacks(IntPtr callbackPtr)
{
    ChartAccessors accessors = (ChartAccessors)Marshal.PtrToStructure(callbackPtr, typeof(ChartAccessors));
    // do stuff with the struct
}
```